# Create permanent DOSKEY in Windows cmd

Tags: windows, command-line, bash, alias

I think the title is pretty self explanatory.

The question is how can I create an alias in a Windows cmd that will also work after I close and then reopen it. For example I would like an alias called `ip` to call the command `ipconfig` or an alias `ls -l` to call `Dir`.

My operating system is Windows 10, in case that makes a difference.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Create a [macro definition file](http://ss64.com/nt/doskey.html), for instance in `notepad`; name it at will and save it anywhere (for instance, in next example I used filename `macros.doskey` in `d:\bat\` folder).

Alternatively, `doskey /macros>d:\bat\macros.doskey` command will list *all current macro definitions* into `d:\bat\macros.doskey` file.

A sample macro definition file could be as follows (note that `==>`  is my command prompt specified by [`prompt $Q$Q$G$S` command](http://ss64.com/nt/prompt.html)):

```
==> type d:\bat\macros.doskey
ls=dir /B $1 
ip=ipconfig $*
```

Then, next commands should do the job:

```
==> reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v Autorun /d "doskey /macrofile=\"d:\bat\macros.doskey\"" /f
The operation completed successfully.

==> reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v Autorun

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor
    Autorun    REG_SZ    doskey /macrofile="d:\bat\macros.doskey"
```

For explanation, read `cmd /?`:

> If `/D` was NOT specified on the command line, then when `CMD.EXE`
> starts, it looks for the following `REG_SZ`/`REG_EXPAND_SZ` registry
> variables, and if either or both are present, they are executed first.
>
> ```
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun
> ```
>
> and/or
>
> ```
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun
> ```

**Disclaimer**: some `AutoRun` settings could eventuate in unlooked-for unwanted behaviour, e.g. as decribed in [Hidden gotcha: The command processor’s AutoRun setting](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071121-00/?p=24433)

Read [Save and restore macro definitions](http://ss64.com/nt/doskey.html); you could prepare a valid `macros.cmd` script file in one step:

```
==> >macros.cmd (@for /F "delims=" %G in ('doskey /macros') do @echo DOSKEY %G)

==> type macros.cmd
DOSKEY ip=ipconfig $*
DOSKEY ls=dir /B $1

==>
```

Please keep in mind that **you cannot run a Doskey macro from a batch file**.

Comment: @nickzoum sorry I can't be more specific; please see updated answer.

Comment: last line, why can't we, and what can we do so that it works ?

Comment: @v.oddou please read [doskey.exe](https://ss64.com/nt/doskey.html) and [Batch file macros](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-macros.html) as well as both useful links to dostips.com below in the latter.

Comment: WARNING: The path can not be relative to the file, it has to be absolute and the file has to continously exist there

Comment: WARNING: do not forget to reopen CMD to take changes effect.

Comment: @Io-oI please ask a regular question…

Comment: I asked you if you could suggest anything to help the operator, I'm not going to open a regular question for that. Forget, forgive...

Comment: @Io-oI Nothing to forgive. I didn't understand your (deleted) comment, sorry…

Comment: That was it and I imagined it. My English is terrible.

Answer (score 35):

1. Create a file to store your macros (DOSKEYs).

   **"C:\bat\macros.doskey"**†

   ```
   ls=dir $* $T
   up=cd.. $T
   ex=exit $T
   np=notepad
   ```
2. Go to the registry editor.

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\
   ```
3. Right-click and add a new "String Value" sub-key. Name it Autorun.

   **Right-click -> New -> String Value**
4. Right-click it and Modify the Value data.

   **Right-click -> Modify -> Value data ->** `DOSKEY /MACROFILE="C:\bat\macros.doskey"`
5. Good to go.

† Note that the file does not have to be saved as a .doskey file.

† Also note that the token `$T` is required if you're making multiple DOSKEYs.

Comment: Apparently the `$T` is only needed if multiple commands are used in a single DOSKEY macro.  You use `$T` to separate the commands, similar to using `&` in a batch file.

Comment: For me using `$T` messed up things. When reopened, cmd was throwing: "invalid macro definition.". So I've simply removed the `$T`'s from the ***macros.doskey*** file and it worked. I would also like to suggest other useful shortcuts: `ip=ipconfig | desktop=cd C:\Users\<your-user>\Desktop\ | gst=git status | gc=git commit | gco=git checkout | gl=gitpull | gpom=git pull origin master | gp=git push | gd=git diff | gb=git branch`

Comment: it started working only if i added the registry file with the name "Autorun"

Answer (score 6):

I do it this way without registry updates.  Pin "Command Prompt" to the task bar, then right click the icon on the task bar; from the popup select "Properties".  In the "Target:" field enter the following:

```
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /F:on /k doskey /macrofile=C:\cmds\macros.txt && Title CONSOLE
```

Then create the `C:\cmds\` folder, open a command prompt and set up your desired "doskey" macros:

```
doskey ip=ipconfig
doskey ls=dir /w
```

Last, create the macro file:

```
doskey /macros > C:\cmds\macros.txt
```

This will change the "Command Prompt" icon in the task bar to invoke `doskey` using the macrofile on startup.  You can use the "Command Prompt" in the START menu if you don't need the macros.

Comment: This is not specific to the Task Bar, though. You could have multiple shortcuts to `cmd.exe` in the Start Menu - or anywhere else - and change the properties to your liking on each and every one of them.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who wants to use doskey macros in conjunction with clink, you can simply follow [this](https://superuser.com/a/1294155/1137538) and add

```
&& doskey.exe /macrofile="C:\Your\Path\To\Your\DosKeyFile"
```

to the regkey "AutoRun" in

```
\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor
```

Mine looks like this,

```
"C:\Your\Path\To\Your\clink.bat" inject --autorun && doskey.exe /macrofile="C:\Your\Path\To\Your\DosKeyFile"
```

Yours can differ.

[source](https://github.com/mridgers/clink/issues/92#issuecomment-454873397)

Comment: @zx485: Congratulations on reaching 2000 reputation points.  (Yes, I see that it actually happened several weeks ago.)  Actually, I believe that you did make three small errors when you edited this post; I have fixed them.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica':  Sorry for my mistakes. I was unsure in some parts. Thanks for correting them.

Answer (score 0):

DOSKEY macros can also be added to a 'shortcut' used to start the command window.
For example, I added a "np" macro to start notepad++ using this method.

- Right-click on the CMD shortcut
- Select "Properties
- In the "Target field" append the following:
  /K doskey np="c:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "$*"

It should look something like this:
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /K doskey np="c:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "$*"

When you start a cmd windows from this modified shortcut, typing np will bring up notepadd++.  You would need to adjust as necessary for your desired commands.