# Trying to write doskey with spaces and "/"

Tags: windows, command-line

I'm trying to right doskey named that takes an argument. It should execute:

```
C:\User\Mercurius\Music\youtube-dl.exe -x --audio-format mp3 -f bestaudio "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ARGUMENT_HERE"
```

I tried this:

```
doskey youtube.com/watch?v=C\User\Mercurius\Music\youtube-dl.exe -x --audio-format mp3 -f bestaudio "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c2gSzYLJ8sY"
```

Then I tried using it but it failed:

```
C:\Users\Mercurius\Music>youtube.com/watch?v=
'youtube.com' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

May you please help

Comment: The  definition of a macro should have a short name and standard paramters used every time and either $1..$n or $* to include the parameters entered when **using** the macro. See https://ss64.com/nt/doskey.html or google for `doskey tutorial`

Comment: Thanks @LotPings I changed it to this: `doskey yt=C\User\Mercurius\Music\youtube-dl.exe -x --audio-format mp3 -f bestaudio "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$1"` but when I try `yt 1234` I get error "The system cannot find the path specified."

Comment: The colon is missing in the drive

Comment: @LotPings if I restart command prompt, the doskey's are not rememberd. is there a way to make them persist?

Comment: Otherwise I have to keep typing `doskey yt=C:\Users\Mercurius\Music\youtube-dl.exe -x --audio-format mp3 -f bestaudio "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$1"`

Comment: Please read this: https://superuser.com/a/1134468/576324