# How do I create aliases on Windows command line, or override existing commands with a script?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe

In bash on Linux platforms, I can write an alias that performs a command, such as:

```
alias cdpics='cd /home/me/Pictures; ls -l'
```

Which will change to my Pictures folder and list its contents.
And even use it to override commands:

```
alias sudo='echo;cd'
```

Which will make the sudo command echo what they pass to it, then change to their home holder.
Is there a way to do this on the Windows command prompt - particularly the latter example?  for instance, can I have the dir or tree command instead execute a batch file?

Comment: [`doskey` macros](https://superuser.com/q/1134368/380318) can override built-in commands - do those do what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

#### Can I have the `dir` or `tree` command instead execute a batch file?

You can use `doskey` for this:

```
doskey dir c:\batch\mydir.cmd
doeskey tree c:\batch\mytree.cmd
```

See [Doskey - recall commands - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/doskey.html)