# (Windows Terminal) How to stop double printing of current working directory when running a command from a doskey macro file?

Tags: windows, command-line, bash, terminal, macros

I've setup a permanent doskey by a doskey macro file as per [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1294155). However, if I use a command that is listed there, it double prints the current working directory (top terminal).

[image]

It seems to have something to do with the $T since it works normally when the macro file only contains 1 doskey alias as per the bottom terminal in the picture.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Why do you use `$T`?

Comment: @grawity because that's what the previous answer says "Also note that the token $T is required if you're making multiple DOSKEYs."

Comment: That's not what it is for. It exists to separate commands _within_ a single alias.

Comment: @grawity oh I see, if you make this comment into an answer I'll accept it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previous thread is incorrect, and the `$T` token should not be used at the end of a macro. It acts as a command separator *within* a single DOSKEY macro definition; not as a separator between multiple definitions. (A regular line break is enough for that.)

DOSKEY macros work by transforming input before it's seen by the actual program (Cmd). Each `$T` in the macro becomes a line break (<kbd>Enter ↵</kbd> keypress) in the expanded output. For example, if you had typed `e Hello!`:

- the macro `e=echo $*` generates `echo Hello!↵`;
- the macro `e=echo $* $T` generates `echo Hello! ↵↵`;
- the macro `e=echo $* $T echo Bye!` generates `echo Hello! ↵ echo Bye!↵`.

(Of course, when making DOSKEY macros for Cmd, you can use the normal `&` or `&&` as a command separator. However, that's not available in other interactive programs – DOSKEY is a generic feature and could be used to make aliases for tools like Netsh, or the MySQL interactive client. Some of them only allow one command per line, therefore a DOSKEY macro needs `$T` to send multiple commands at once.)