# DOSKEY with FOR variable cannot be processed syntactically at this point when defined in macro definition file

Tags: cmd.exe, alias

When creating the following alias

```
DOSKEY echoall=FOR %p IN (*) DO echo %p
```

in CMD on Windows 10 the alias works as expected printing all the files in the directory. However I tried to define this makro in a separate makro definition file like [described in this post](https://superuser.com/a/1134468/1281238). When trying to run the same makro then I get the error message

```
"p" cannot be processed syntactically at this point.
```

How can I resolve this so that `%p` actually gets substituted by the value like when defining the makro in the current cmd?

Answer (score 1):

In a makro definition file the `%p` has to be escaped with an extra `%`. So the following will work:

```
DOSKEY echoall=FOR %%p IN (*) DO echo %%p
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside batch scripts you have to use 2 percentage signs instead of one in the normal command line