Batch file for dynamic tab title in Windows Terminal
Created a batch file
title.bat
@echo off
prompt $P$G
doskey cd=cd $* ^& for %%i in (.) do @title %%~nxi

and appended it to the Developer Command Prompt profile within Windows Terminal:

cmd.exe /k "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat" -startdir=none
-arch=x64 -host_arch=x64 && C:\Users\johndoe\Documents\title.bat

This ensures that every time you change directories using the cd command, the tab title dynamically reflects the new current working directory:

Is there a simpler way to achieve that?

What part of it is complex? You could use an autorun entry if you want that behavior in all CMD windows like https://superuser.com/a/1134468/673426 for example, but I think what you have is good to limit it to that wt profile
